# 2d array sort wih conditions

Tags: arrays, matlab

i have 2d array which consist of

1. ). 1st row for y axis coordinate of point(i)
2. ). 2nd row for x axis coordinate of point(i)
3. ). i

let consider following

```
a(1,:)=[1,2,3,4,10,11,12,13,19,20,21,22];

a(2,:)=[4,1,3,2,4,3,1,2,3,2,4,1];

a(3,:)=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
```

according to the above array 'a' it shows that it is shorted according to the first column(according to y coordinates).

but in my case i want to sort them with following steps

- identify the position where the difference between two consecutive values of y coordinates (values of a(a,:)) changes rapidly and
- sort the values between those rapidly change with respect to x coordination (a(2,:))

let consider the following

a =

```
 1     2     3     4    10    11    12    13    19    20    21    22
 4     1     3     2     4     3     1     2     3     2     4     1
 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
 0     1     1     1     6     1     1     1     6     1     1     1
```

here 4th row represent the difference between two consecutive y coordinates (a(1,:))

in there 5th value shows rapid change so i want consider first 4 value set and analyze the x and y coordinates w.r.t x coordinate (a(2,:))

in same way for whole array and following array represented the expected results.

a =

```
 2     4     3     1    12    13    11    10    22    20    19    21
 1     2     3     4     1     2     3     4     1     2     3     4
 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
 0     1     1     1     6     1     1     1     6     1     1     1
```

note by:

the 3rd column value should not be changed.

the rapid changed is not obtained in same period like in above it varying.(in my case it happened after every 4 values )

the rapid change is not 6 for every instant (let the solution should convenience for values greater than 3)

- *can any one help me to code this**

Comment: *can any one help me to code this* one can help, for the right price of course. In general it's good practise to either pay upfront, or add code of yourself to show you have put an effort into solving this. Either way tends to entice people here.

Comment: You mention "rapid change" several times. This is ambiguous, please be exact about what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a little confused as to what you want. This code will group your array into blocks where they change only by a normal amount (specified by variable normalchange). It will produce a cell array where each cell is a group of similar elements. In this instance normal change is 1 then you get three groups.

Let me know if this helps.

```
a(1,:)=[1,2,3,4,10,11,12,13,19,20,21,22];

a(2,:)=[4,1,3,2,4,3,1,2,3,2,4,1];

a(3,:)=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];

interestedmembers=0;
thingtoanalyse={};
startOfMembers=1;
normalchange = 1;
for i=2:size(a,2)
    if a(1,i)-a(1,i-1) > normalchange
        thingtoanalyse{end+1}=a(:,startOfMembers:startOfMembers+...
            interestedmembers);
        interestedmembers=0;
        startOfMembers = i-1;
    end
    interestedmembers = interestedmembers+1;
end
% catch everything after the last jump and classify as interesting.
thingtoanalyse{end+1} = a(:,startOfMembers:end);
```